# Fetch data from database

Tags: c#, sql

I created a table named 'Gift_Info' in a database named 'shop'. In the table,there are 3 columns (ID,UserEmail,BDayDate). I created Events.cshtml in /Views/Home :

```
var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  var db = Database.Open ("shop");
  var sa = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
  var sql = "SELECT BDayDate, ID FROM Gift_Info WHERE UserEmail = @0";
  var result = db.Query(sql, sa);
  var data = result.Select(x => new
  {
      id = x.Giftee,
      title = x.Giftee,
      allDay = true
  }).ToArray();

  Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
  Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: events: '/Events.cshtml' ? => i think it should be your method name that returns data result not your .cshtml page name in event

Comment: it supposedto be location right?

Comment: if your method return json formatted data of event properties than it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  Instead of creating objects manually, you will go to the database.  This will work to call a controller action or a method.  If you want to call an asmx you can, but be sure to turn on the script attribute:

Controller methods, or your methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class eventsClass {
        public IList<YouWillGetThisFromDB> events = new List<YouWillGetThisFromDB>();
    }

    public class YouWillGetThisFromDB
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title {get; set;}
        public string start {get; set;}
        public bool allDay {get; set;}
    }

    public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents()
    {
        YouWillGetThisFromDB you = new YouWillGetThisFromDB
        {
            id = "theId",
            title = "theTitle",
            start = "1/5/2017",
            allDay = true
        };
        eventsClass ec = new eventsClass();
        ec.events.Add(you);

        return Json(ec.events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }

    public ActionResult Index15()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head title="apdh">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.print.css ">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false
                , events: '/Home/GetCalendarEvents'
            });
        }); </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried this before. But i'm do not know how to retrieve data from db in controller

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ganYd) is a .NET fiddle with fullcalendar working. It shows how to call the Controller which supplies the start and end dates which could be used to limit the data returned from the database. It then returns events that are displayed on the calendar.